# Flutter App updates is not working in playstore. Showing can't install

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]

App is available in playstore. The install is working. But its not updating. Just downloading the update and showing the popup in the screenshot.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. Did you already read the the Help Center page on what questions are on-topic here? If so, can you explain to my why this is on topic? (since I'm not sure). If not, please read it and consider whether your question is on-topic here. If you're not sure where to ask this question, you can ask on meta.stackexchange.com using the \[site-recommendation\] tag.

Comment: I believe this issue is something related to the app. Because this issue is appearing for multiple users.

Comment: I have already seen a exact  similar issue in stack overflow but no answer are find out.

Comment: If you saw an exact same question with no answers, then don't ask it again. Follow that post to get notified of updates, upvote it, and place a bounty when you have enough rep. See [/help/no-one-answers](/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: Can you please provide a link here to that question you are referring to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter app not able to update on Google Play Store (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76658506/flutter-app-not-able-to-update-on-google-play-store-android)

Answer (score 0):

We ware psuhed the 2.0 of the app. A sudden upgade from 1.0 to 2.0 cause this issue.

We have uninstall the app and installed. So the current version is 2.0.
After we pusblushed a new update 2.1. 2.1 we can updte wwithout any issue.

Comment: Hi Shahin, I'm also facing the same issue, but my version is 1.0 and the builds no increments by 2, here the last version is 1.0 build no 24 and the update is version 1.0 with build no 26, do you have any idea on this?