# Flutter app not able to update on Google Play Store (Android)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My flutter app not able to update from Google Play Store

**Step to reproduce the error:**

1. I build a signed APK in release mode from Android studio which has lower version number and version code ***(version 1.0.2+1)***
2. When install the signed APK, it will prompt the update pop up and direct me to Play Store. However, after it finish updating, i got error **Can't install AppName**. Refer `image 1` attached below. My app on Play Store have a version of ***(version 1.0.3+24)***

**note:**

1. The APK that was build for Android studio and AAB files that I submitted to the Play Store have been signed using the identical keystore.jks.
2. Tested on device with Android 11 and Android 12

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa7Sf.png)

Listed below are several instances of the same issue that have been mentioned, yet without any provided solutions.

1. [Cann't install the app message on play store in Flutter App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74820864/cannt-install-the-app-message-on-play-store-in-flutter-app)
2. [my flutter app is not install from play store after update the new version in play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75926893/my-flutter-app-is-not-install-from-play-store-after-update-the-new-version-in-pl)
3. [Flutter App updates is not working in playstore. Showing can't install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75035529/flutter-app-updates-is-not-working-in-playstore-showing-cant-install)

Would anyone happen to know the cause of this error? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

After uninstalling the signed APK generated from Android Studio, I successfully installed the app from the Play Store. Unfortunately, I haven't found any other solutions to address the issue.

**[INFO].[Edited on 20230711]**
**[6:17 am, Tuesday, 11 July 2023, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)]**
**[Purpose] Added info about upload signing when building APK and .abb file for Play Store**

Before upload the .abb file to Play Store, i did sign the app with an upload key (keystore.jks)

[Releases signed by Google Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovS7p.png)

**[INFO].[Edited on 20230711]**
**[3:04 pm Tuesday, 11 July 2023, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)]**
**[Purpose] Update Answer**

I have added **the solution** at the Answer section

Comment: Did you sign the APK with the signing or upload key? Google Play Store can generate it's own key if you turn on app bundles and app signing if you don't pay attention. You can check the signature of the key that google uses in the play console.

Comment: hi @AlexanderHoffmann, yes i did sign the APK that i generated from Android studio with the upload key and also .aab file that i upload to play store

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann hi, i have updated my post, can you help to elaborate more on "Google Play Store can generate it's own key if you turn on app bundles and app signing if you don't pay attention." ? Are you trying to say that i do no need to sign my apk if  i let play store handle my .abb signing? thank you

Comment: Did you try to generate a signed .aab and directly upload it to the Play Store ?

Comment: hi @ItzDavi yes, this is what i did, the .aab is signed by the same keystore.jks that was used to build the apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a signing key mismatch here.
As I understand it, you generate a release APK locally and sign it with your signing key.

You then install the APK locally. Afterwards you go to your app's Google Play Store page and try to download the newer app update which you also signed with the same key and uploaded as an Android App Bundle.

I believe the problem is that when you enabled Play App Signing, you did not provide your own signing key as the signing key for Play Store.

Usually, Google Play Store will automatically generate it's own signing key unless you explicitly tell it not to do so. It will use your previous key only as an upload key. The goal of the upload key is to verfiy that your uploaded AAB is from you. When the Play Console generates APKs from the AAB it will however use it's own signing key.

You can check which key is actually used in the Google Play Console. Go to your app's Play Console page, select "App Integrity" in the "Setup" category. On the right side, select the "App Signing" tab.

Now you will see the signatures of the actually signing key that is used by Google Play Console.

[image: App Signing overview in the Google Play Console]

Comment: yes, the above scenario is what's happening right now. If you could spare a few moments, I would be thankful for your advice regarding on how to handle this situation, thank you

Comment: What do you try to achieve? If you only install and update apps through Play Store, everything is fine. You just can't generate a version locally, distribute it and then update it later through Play Store. If you want an APK that is compatible with the Play Store version to distribute it elsewhere, you'll need to download a universal APK from the Play Console. The Play Store will sign the universal APK with the signing key.

Comment: ok, i got what you mean already. Thanks for your guidance, appreciate <3

Comment: Do you mind accepting my answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

**Issue**

The problem is that I used a locally generated signed APK, and when I tried to update the app from the Play Store, it caused an error.

**Solution**

Download the universal APK from Google Play Console and the app is able to update normally from Play Store.

**Step to get the Universal APK from Google Play Console**

Google Play Console > Select your App > select `Production` tab on the side bar > Releases > View release details > Under App bundle section, select the arrow on the right end > select Download tab > Signed, universal APK (download this APK)

[Signed, universal APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRemJ.png)

Credit and Thanks to @Alexander Hoffmann for helping to solve this issue, thank you